# Dividing seconds by 60 twice to get hours results in zero

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert the number of seconds contained in a duration into hours by dividing the `duration.getSeconds()` value by 60 twice.

However when I do this the number is being converted into 0.0, instead of an actual value. I imagine this is because the number is too small to be represented, however  I have used doubles to try and represent the number and it still doesn't work.

In the below code please assume `startTime` and `endTime` are valid LocalTimes produced by two separate calls to `LocalTime.now()`

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime); //duration in sec
        double durationInSec = duration.getSeconds();
        double durationInHours = durationInSec / 60 / 60;
```

Comment: Try using BigDecimal instead and see if it works.

Comment: @Marvin If the difference is milliseconds it gives 0

Comment: `long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(duration.getSeconds());`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting the issue here. If there is less than 1 second between startTime and endTime, should durationInHours really be something else than 0?

Comment: @SDJ Is correct. OP should use `duration.getNano()` to get time.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch [`Duration.toHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toHours()) is a shorter way to get a whole number of total elapsed hours.

Answer (score 2):

## Works for me

```
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.of ( 11 , 30 );
    LocalTime stop = start.plusHours ( 2 );
    Duration d = Duration.between ( start , stop );

    double seconds = d.toSeconds ();
    double hours = seconds / 60 / 60;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/gRJBvN).

> start.toString() = 11:30
>
> stop.toString() = 13:30
>
> d.toString() = PT2H
>
> seconds = 7200.0
>
> hours = 2.0

Tip: When you know you want to work with fractions of `double`, append `d` to your numeric literals to avoid any confusion over the compiler's integer-to-fraction conversion and up/downscaling the types. Be explicit. So in your code, append each `60` with a `d`. May not be necessary here, but removes ambiguity for the reader at least.

```
double hours = seconds / 60d / 60d ;
```

## <1 second = 0 hours

As others commented, if your elapsed time was less than a full second, your code results in a zero.

A `Duration` is internally represented by a count of whole seconds *plus* a fractional second as a count of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Your call to [`Duration::getSeconds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#getSeconds()) retrieves the **whole seconds, without the fractional second**. So for a duration of PT0.5S, `getSeconds` returns zero. Zero divided by sixty divided by sixty equals zero.

```
    Duration d = Duration.parse ( "PT0.5S" );  // Half a second. 
    double hours = d.getSeconds () / 60d / 60d;
```

> hours: 0.0

You should instead call [`Duration::toNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toNanos()) to get a total number of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) elapsed. And adjust your division.

```
    Duration d = Duration.parse ( "PT0.5S" );  // Half a second.
    long nanos = d.toNanos () ;
    double hours = nanos / 1_000_000_000d / 60d / 60d ;
```

> hours: 1.388888888888889E-4

## Avoid fractional hours

By the way, let me suggest that **fractional hours is a poor way to handle spans-of-time**. Hours, minutes, seconds, and such are not amenable to such decimal math.

Besides that, the floating-point types such as `double` are [inherently inaccurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems).

Use the Java classes intended for this purpose: [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) and `Period`. When reporting or exchanging textually the value of these objects, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format. As seen above, 2 hours is represented by `PT2H`.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT2H" ) ;
```